# Docker Alpine: Error loading MySQLdb module

Tags: mysql, django, docker, mariadb, alpine-linux

I am building an **Alpine** based image of a **Django** application with **MariaDB** and I can't figure out which dependency I should add to my `Dockerfile` so that my app could properly connect to the DB.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Well, I thought I did. From what I read [in this article](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-9-installing-popular-packages-on-alpine), in [this discussion](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/181), `mariadb-dev` is in **Alpine** the equivalent of `default-libmysqlclient-dev` in **Debian** based system. Furthermore, the [mysql-client package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/mysql-client) in Alpine is merely a dummy package (containing *mariadb-dev*, *mariadb-client*, etc etc). Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/cms

# install mysqlclient
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev\
    && apk del build-deps

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /usr/src/cms/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/cms/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/cms/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/cms/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I tried to add `mariadb-client`, to use `mysql-client` instead. 
I also tried to add `RUN pip install django-mysql`. Nothing seems to change. I successfully build **Postgres** Django apps without any problem but, when it comes to MySQl vs MariaDB // Debian vs Alpine, I feel confused. Any insight?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems you're missing the `MySQLdb` Python module, for which you should install the `mysqlclient` Python package: `pip install mysqlclient`.

On Alpine, pip will build `mysqlclient` from source, so you'll need `gcc` and `musl-dev` for this setup step, hence you'll need to postpone `apk del build-deps` to after Python modules are installed.

Fixed Dockerfile snippet:

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev

...

RUN pip install mysqlclient  

RUN apk del build-deps
```

Comment: I am doing exactly the same, but still receiving the same error. Can you please help?

Comment: yep. doesn't work for me either. long and lengthy crash of the dependency build.

Comment: The only necessary dependency is `mariadb-connector-c`. No need to install the big fat `mariadb-dev`.

Comment: To clarify the comment by @Rockallite , you only need `mariadb-connector-c` for the `mysqlclient` python module to function post-install, but you DO need `mariadb-dev` to build it.  This is relevant if you are trying to slim your Docker image down.

Comment: so you can install mariadb-dev to build and later uninstall it and keep only with mariadb-connector-c

Comment: In this example, deleting `build-deps` in a dedicated `RUN` instructions will keep it inside the main image. All above commands should be performed inside the same `RUN` instrucitons in order to make image thinner.

Answer (score 7):

Mainly you need to install [mariadb-connector-c-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=mysql_config&path=&name=*&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=x86_64) package. But only this package will give compilation errors. So additionally you will need to add gcc and musl-dev packages into Dockerfile. This will make Django and MySQL work within alpine image.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add gcc musl-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

2023.05.06 - 2023.06.08
During this time I explicitly used the following code and it worked:

```
RUN apk add musl-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev gcc && \
    pip install mysqlclient && \
    pip cache purge && \
    apk del --rdepends --purge musl-dev gcc
```

But now, 2023.06.25, I found that I had to add `mariadb-dev` to successfully install mysqlclient.