# Unable to build a docker for Django and Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I am building an application with Djnago and MySql. But I have error while build. This is my code:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'repository'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/repository
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==3.2
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-crispy-forms==1.11.0
django-js-asset==1.2.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
mysqlclient==1.4.6
xhtml2pdf==0.2.5
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'repository',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

**This is My Error**

```
>     #9 10.61 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==1.4.6 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2,
> 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0)
>     #9 10.61 ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==1.4.6
>     ------
>     executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I am able to build the image if I remove the mysqlclient library from the requirements.txt.
Thanks before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Alpine: Error loading MySQLdb module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048631/docker-alpine-error-loading-mysqldb-module)

Comment: Is there some other error before this?  (Note that 1.4.6 is in the list of versions pip was able to find, so you have a valid version pin in `requirements.txt`.)

Comment: @S.Sachith Oh yes. it really works. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

**Note on Python 3**
If you are using `python3`

> You may need to install the Python and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev # Debian / Ubuntu
sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel # Red Hat / CentOS
brew install mysql-client # macOS (Homebrew)
```

You can refere to [mysqlclient 1.4.6](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/1.4.6/) for more details.